# Unconventional SQL query - Select rows depending on the occurence of the values in other rows

Tags: sql, select

I need to create a little unusual SQL query.

There are two special columns in the table (**`COL_LEFT`** and **`COL_RIGHT`**) and two special values (**`A`** and **`B`**) that can randomly appear in both colums along with other values (`C`, `D`, `E` ,`F` ..).

I need to select all rows that meet these specific conditions:

1. There has to be **`A`** or **`B`** in either of the two colums but not both at the same time. (i.e. there has to be either **`A`** or **`B`** in one of the columns and some other value in the other column)
2. If there is a value **`A`** in one of the columns and another value (let's call it `X`) in the other column, there has to be at least one row in the table where there is a value **`B`** in one of the columns and the value `X` in the other column and vice versa (If there is a value **`A`** ...)

In other words I need to select all rows with combination of **`A`**-`X` (or `X`-**`A`**) and **`B`**-`X` (or `X`-**`B`**) only when both combinations **`A`**-`X` (or `X`-**`A`**) and **`B`**-`X` (or `X`-**`B`**) are present in the table.

The columns are interchangeable in a way that combination of **`A`**-`X` is considered the same as `X`-**`A`**.

Hopefully I made myself clear.

Here's a table that shows how it should work. The highlighted rows (green) are those that meet the conditions.

[image]

EDIT:

The database is (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.

Here is the data (this is all I have at this point):

```
 COL_LEFT   COL_RIGHT       RESULT
    A   F       SELECT
    E   K       LEAVE OUT
    A   E       SELECT
    B   A       LEAVE OUT
    M   D       LEAVE OUT
    A   C       SELECT
    L   B       LEAVE OUT
    C   A       SELECT
    E   A       SELECT
    C   A       SELECT
    D   L       LEAVE OUT
    F   C       LEAVE OUT
    C   B       SELECT
    F   B       SELECT
    H   N       LEAVE OUT
    A   S       LEAVE OUT
    B   F       SELECT
    C   F       LEAVE OUT
    E   B       SELECT
    B   K       LEAVE OUT
    S   M       LEAVE OUT
    M   A       LEAVE OUT
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please provide a title that actually summarizes your question, the actual database you're using (you need to **know** this, not just guess!), provide the necessary DDL and to setup the example, and demonstrate some effort towards solving your own problem.

Comment: The database is (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB. What do you mean by "providing" the necessary DDL?

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, really helps clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Bohemian: I know. But I really don't know any of the syntax used in those nested queries and even the concept of this. So I could only put together some kind of nonsense but it would be more confusing for readers than the description with the table as an example.

Comment: Bohemian: It is quite a simple problem (I mean the assignment) but as you can see the solution is not that trivial whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are describing looks like this. Tested with your sample data:

```
with Tbl as (
    select a.*
       , case when col_left='A' or col_right='A' then 'A' else 'B' end A_OR_B
       , case when col_left='A' or col_left='B' then col_right else col_left end as VAL_TO_MATCH
    from yourtable a
    where 
     (col_left in ('A','B') and col_right <> col_left and col_right not in ('A','B'))
     OR 
     (col_left not in ('A','B') and col_right<>col_left and col_right in ('A','B'))
)
select * 
from 
   Tbl t1
   where exists (select *
                 from Tbl t2
                 where t1.A_OR_B<>t2.A_OR_B
                   and t1.VAL_TO_MATCH=t2.VAL_TO_MATCH
                )
```

UPDATE: Pre-calculate the type of rec as A or B and also derive a column to represent the non-A_or_B side to compare.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Unfortunately I don't have any data that I can make public here to test it but so far it seems it works. Nevertheless I need a little more time to go thru the query and actually understand the logic of it.

Comment: I already found a mistake. Your query select rows even when there are combinations with one of the basic values (A or B). i.e. for example there 2 combinations of A-C (A-C and C-A) but there is no combination with B (there is no B-C or C-B)  (Just to be clear this new example is different from the data that I provided in the table above)

Comment: That is what I meant by providing sample data in text form

Comment: I think there is same mistake as in the previous version. The problem is probably in the line: "case when col_left='A' or col_right='A' then 'A' else 'B' end A_OR_B" it will result as 'B' even if there is no 'B' in neither of the columns.

Comment: Anyhow I am not familiar with this sql syntax. Why is there commas at the start of each line before "case when" and why is there a simple "end" A_OR_B in one line and "end as" VAL_TO_MATCH in the other line?

Comment: The line: "case when col_left='A' or col_right='A' then 'A' else 'B' end A_OR_B" might be ok, since there is a subsequent condition "where 
     (col_left in ('A','B')" and vice versa. But it still does not work correctly for some reason.

Comment: EDIT: My mistake. It actually seems to work. Let me check properly.

Comment: tinazmu: I'm here just to confirm that it really works as it should! Many thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, somehow I didn't get your messages, I would have replied, otherwise. Let me know if you have an unanswered question.